# Javascript - How to push data inside a map function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I've got the following data structure stored in a useState hook.

```js
const [data, setData] = useState([
  {
  id: uniqid(),
  title: "",
  content:[
    id: uniqid(),
    title: "",
  ]
  },
  {
  id: uniqid(),
  title: "",
  content:[
    id: uniqid(),
    title: "",
  ],
  }
])
```

I've got a button where the user can add something to the content array, and I'm calling handleReport as below -

```js
const handleAddReport = uniqueID =>{
  const object = {
    id: uniqid(),
    title:"",
  }
  const formData = [...data];
  formData.map(section=>{
   section.content.map(report=>{
    if(report.id === uniqueID){
      section.content.push(object);
    };
   });
  });
  
  setForm(formData);
}
```

However, this isn't changing the form data at all. I'm not exactly sure how I could get it to work, any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: You need to return `section` in `map`.

Comment: `map` with no return is pointless. You may as well use `forEach`, or more to the point instead of looping the entire set just `find` the single item you want to update and update it.

Comment: Reiterating what @Jamiec said; You are misusing map if you do one of two things: have side effects in your map callbacks, ignore the return value of map. Also, you should avoid modifying data structures; if you can keep them immutable, there will be fewer surprises. Lastly, you don't seem to be calling `setData` anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are not returning anything from the map.

```
const handleAddReport = uniqueID =>{
  const object = {
    id: uniqid(),
    title:"",
  }
  const formData = [...data];
  const newData = formData.map(section=> {
     if(section.id === uniqueID){
      section.content.push(object);
    }
   return section;
  });
  
  setForm(newData);
}
```

But instead of comparing the unqiueId another approach would be to pass the index of your data array. So that we can avoid `map` .

```
const handleAddReport = dataIndex =>{
  const object = {
    id: uniqid(),
    title:"",
  }
// deep clone the data
const clonedData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
// since the data is cloned you can mutate it directly 
clonedData[dataIndex].content.push(object);
setForm(clonedData)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
const onAddReport = (uniqid: number) => {
    const obj = {
        id: 3,
        title: ''
    };
    const formData = [...data];
    const mappedData = formData.map((data) => data.id === uniqid ? ({ ...data, content: [...data.content, obj] }) : data)
    setData(mappedData);
}
```